# Query to find users with one row in table

Tags: mysql

I have a table "users" which has multiple columns in which column "status" has multiple values like 1,0,3,2,4. There is column "user_id" which doesn't contain unique values since, this is foreign key of another table called "user_master".

so here in "users" table we have multiple values of the one user.

So, Here is my actual query is that i would like to write a sql query to find users has only one entry in table "users" with particular status value.

For e.g. I would like to fetch all such users with status=2  and their entry in table is not more than 1. Like if user has multiple entries with status 2,1,4 in table which should not be return in query.

It should yield those users which has only one entry in table and which is of status =  2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched it and found answer for it.

And query goes like this.

```
select count(id) as cnt,
user_id,status from users 
group by user_id 
having cnt < 2 and status=2
```

First it will group the things having count less than 2 and then which will check for status.

Answer (score 1):

That must be what you use:

```
Select count(u.user_id) AS cnt, u.* 
from user u
where u.status = 2
group by u.user_id, u.status
having cnt = 1;
```

Comment: this query is giving me users with status =2 up to that it is ok. but i need the user who has entry in table which is not more than 1..

this query is failed to do so.

Comment: I have made some minor changes in my question please go through it . you will get my exact requirement.

Thanks for your efforts. :)

Comment: from every status, can you send a short sample

Comment: Yes for any status.. if i wish the same for status 4 it should give those users.
 who have only one entry in table and which is of status = 4

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH tmp AS(
SELECT Stud_Id,COUNT(*) AS 'Count' FROM Student_tbl GROUP BY Stud_Id
)

SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE Count = 1 AND Status = 2
```

You have to add field in GROUP BY Clause whichever you want to use in SELECT clause.

Comment: This should work! WITH tmp AS(
SELECT Stud_Id,COUNT(*) AS 'Count',Status FROM Student_tbl GROUP BY Stud_Id,Status
)

SELECT * FROM tmp where Status = 1